# Why angular $http.get() modifies my URL?

Tags: angularjs

I have a code like that:

```
$http.get('http://localhost/goalkeeper/public/api/goal/' + goalId + '/logs/')
.success(function(data){
    console.log(data)
});
```

But Angular sends the request to the following URL:

```
http://localhost/api/goal/1/logs
```

Why does it trim `goalkeeper/public` away?

What's funny, I have a POST request in the same controller and it works fine without modifying the URL.

What's even more funny - when I `console.log` the URL:

```
'http://localhost/goalkeeper/public/api/goal/' + goalId + '/logs/'
```

Before or after the request code - it just returns the right result.

Here is the full controller code - http://pastebin.com/X3cjAfbZ

Comment: Angular doesn't do that. Something's wrong in your code. Post a **complete** example reproducing the problem.

Comment: I have posted the controller code, though I have replaced "http://localhost/goalkeeper/public" - the problem is still the same even if I hardcode that

Comment: What's so hard to understand about "complete"? Here is a **complete** example: http://plnkr.co/edit/fEqxQPkdq8ooUZpYJ1eg?p=preview. But of course, it works fine. So, if you want help, post a **complete** example reproducing the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet here I have reproduced it - http://plnkr.co/edit/TzNVMRX9vRc8Lb03lxH0, but on plunker it sends URL to the right direction, and I don't know whats wrong in my app, cause I don't have more code. I think it is somehow related to 'localhost'

Comment: I ended up creating a virtual host which solved the problem, but the problem is really awkward. And I am wondering what could have caused it.